# SSRS Fit To Page when exporting to .pdf or excel

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that is in Legal size (8 1/2 x 14), but when it is exported in .pdf or excel, it is extending to second page because of too many fields being displayed on the report.  Is there a configuration that I can set-up within SSRS environment to "fit to page" so that when the report Is exported in .pdf or excel it will fit to page and not go on second page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure your page layout is okay but you also need to see the sizes of other objects like Report Body, Tablix, Images, Text boxes etc.

The total width of any object should be slightly less than the report body width and the report body width itself should be slightly less than report page width minus margins.

e.g. If report width is 8 inches, and 0.5 inches margin on both sides, body width should be slightly less than 7 inches (i.e. 6.95 inches).

And then the width of inner objects (i.e. Tablix, Text boxes etc) should be up to 6.94 inches.

Once the report started looking good, you can increase the width of objects and body to see up to the maximum size where it remains within the page.

On top of that, when previewing reports in the report designer, use the Print layout as the page view.

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: I change the layout to Custom 16 inch width 11 inch height, and it fits perfectly in PDF.

Comment: Sweet. Nice to know :)