# SSRS Report data moves up for certain records when downloaded to pdf

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS report. In the 2nd rectangle in my rdl, i have few controls like tablix and textboxes.
when i generate report and download the report to pdf, report looks good for few records, but for few records the data in entire 2nd page is moved up by almost 2 cms.
I am not able to figure out the reason for this.
Please let me know what might be the reason for this and how this can be resolved.

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954707/ssrs-fit-to-page-when-exporting-to-pdf-or-excel

Comment: Thanks for your input.  But in my case date is moving up in the same page and not entering a new page. And also as mentioned body width is 8.364 with left and right margin 0 which is less than page width 8.5. Width of object is 8.302 which is less than body width.